# Adding Polygon data to an OSM map on ThingsBoard

Tags: widget, openstreetmap, thingsboard

I'm trying to integrate Polygons data into an OpenStreetMap on a ThingsBoard map widget.
I have the data saves as a GeoJSON file and I also converted it to a list of polygons (another list) made of [LAT, long] values.
Not sure how to add the file into the map and there isn't a choice to use my own OpenStreetMap map/link.

I tried inserting the following lines into the "onInit" function of the widget but can't make it load successfully.
Here is the code I added to the 'controllerScript' attribute on the widget's JSON.

```
self.onInit = function() {
\n\tself.ctx.map = new TbMapWidgetV2('openstreet-map', false, self.ctx);
\n\tself.ctx.map.location.polygon = self.ctx.map.createPolygon(
ListOfLatLnGPolygons, self.ctx.map.location.settings, self.ctx.map.location, 
function (event) 
\n{
\n\tself.ctx.map.callbacks.onLocationClick(self.ctx.map.location);
\n\tself.ctx.map.locationPolygonClick(event, self.ctx.map.location);
\n}, self.ctx.map.location.dsIndex);
\n\tself.ctx.map.polygons.push(self.ctx.map.location.polygon);
\n}
\nself.onDataUpdated = function() {
\n\tself.ctx.map.update();
\n}
\n
\nself.onResize = function() {
\n\tself.ctx.map.resize();
\n}
\n
\nself.getSettingsSchema = function() {
\n\treturn TbMapWidgetV2.settingsSchema('openstreet-map');
\n}
\n
\nself.getDataKeySettingsSchema = function() {
\n\treturn TbMapWidgetV2.dataKeySettingsSchema('openstreet-map');
\n}
\n
\nself.actionSources = function() {
\n\treturn TbMapWidgetV2.actionSources();
\n}
\n
\nself.onDestroy = function() {
\n}
\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited the code and made it work as follows on the onInit() function.

```
self.onInit = function() {
self.ctx.map = new TbMapWidgetV2('openstreet-map',
        false, self.ctx);
    var tbMap = self.ctx.map;
    var coordinates = [[lat1,long1],[lat2,long2],[lat2,long3]]; 
    // I manually entered the coordinates
    var latLangs = [];

    self.ctx.map.configureLocationsSettings();
    self.ctx.settings.showPolygon = true;
    self.ctx.settings.polygonColor = "#FE7569";
    self.ctx.settings.polygonStrokeColor = "#000000";
    coordinates.forEach(function(coord) {
        latLangs.push(tbMap.map.createLatLng(
            coord[1], coord[0]));
    })
    tbMap.map.createPolygon(latLangs, self.ctx.settings,
        location, true, null);

    tbMap.update();
}
```

I still don't know why, but this answer only shows the polygon on the map, but it is not clickable in order to use it with a "on polygon click" action.

Comment: did you had to create a custom widget in order to insert the self.onInit code? I can't find where to insert it in the default widget.